# Can I use ftl instead of HTML pages in Angular 6 Components

Tags: angular6

I need to use ftl pages instead of HTML in angular 6 components. I have created a simple angular 6 project using angular cli and changed html page of app component to ftl page and when I tried to compile I'm getting an error.

Is it possible to use ftl pages in angular 6?